# Why are list elements appearing outside the unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically added list that gets its values from an object array.  However, when looking at the inspector, it shows the list elements after the closing `ul` tag, but the styles are still applying as though the list elements are inside the `ul` element.  Why is this happening?

**HTML**

```
<div id="portfolio_page" class="page">
    <aside>
    </aside>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var Portfolio = {
    Completed: ["SPARTAN", "Custom Select Menu", "Popup"],
    Ongoing: ["Hello"],
    Future_Projects: [],
    Clients: []
}

for(var key in Portfolio){
    var item = key.replace("_", " ");
    $("#portfolio_page aside").append("<h1>" +item +"</h1><ul>");
    for(var i = 0; i < Portfolio[key].length; i++){
        $("#portfolio_page aside").append("<li>" + Portfolio[key][i]+"</li>");
        console.log(key[i]);
    }
    $("#portfolio_page aside").append("</ul>");
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zfz22ebm/)

[image]

Comment: This is not how works `append()` http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, I realized what I had done wrong almost as soon as I posted the question.  That's what I get for not paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the unordered list first add items to it then append it to the main container ...

```
 $("#portfolio_page aside").append("<h1>" +item +"</h1>");
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
for(var i = 0; i < Portfolio[key].length; i++){
    $ul.append("<li>" + Portfolio[key][i]+"</li>");
    console.log(key[i]);
}
$("#portfolio_page aside").append($ul);
```

You are getting the elements outside the unordered list because when you were opening it outside the loop [With the closing tag]. The automatically created the ul element [because of the browser attempting to correct the markup closures].

When the list elements were appended it was not being appended to the list [because it was already closed by the browser], but to the main container because it was properly referenced since it was existing before.

Hence, whenever a new container containing individual items need to be appended, make sure you getting a reference to it, add items to it and finally add the element to the main container where you want it to be displayed.

Hope it helps!